# Symfony framework database migration

Tags: php, laravel, symfony

I am laravel dev and now working with Symfony for few days. I have clone a git form bitbucket and wanted to migrate the database. But on laravel we can easily migrate all tables to database I cant find option on  Symfony. How can I migrate my tables to mysql? Do I need menually import tables to mysql?

Comment: What you are asking is unclear. Why your database has to be migrated ? From what to what ? What do you mean by migrate ?

Comment: i think since he is laravel artisan guy he talking with lara language. On lara its "migration" so. @COil

Comment: So he wants to generates all the entity class stuff?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No.
1.Find `app/config/parameters.yml`:

```
parameters:
    database_host:      localhost
    database_name:      databaseName
    database_user:      root
    database_password:  password
```

2.Create database, with console:

In Symfony 2: `php app/console doctrine:database:create`

In Symfony 3: `php bin/console doctrine:database:create`

3.Migrate Tables

In Symfony 2: `php app/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`

In Symfony 3: `php bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate`

Comment: What makes you think the question is about Doctrine?

Comment: @Alister Bulman thinks the same as me,  so is question  about Symfony or Doctrine?

Answer (score 0):

Symfony has the `bin/console` command (in older versions it may be at `app/console`). If there already is the database and tables, but there are migrations that have not been run, you can run all the available migrations with

```
bin/console doctrine:migrations:migrate
```

You can see all the other commands with

```
bin/console list
```

or just Symfony commands that deal with database & table creation, migration and more.

```
bin/console list doctrine
```